# Querying a row with condition and minimum

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Find the makers of the cheapest color printers. Result set: maker, price

Tables:

- Product (maker, model, type)
- Printer (code, model, color, type, price)

`model` is `Printer`'s foreign key to `Product`.

(source: sql-ex.ru)

The first step is to get `model`(s) of the minimum `price` row(s) with `colored='y'`.

The question boils down to how to do something like (incorrect code):

```
SELECT MIN(price), model
FROM Printers;
```

However when I `SELECT MIN(price)`, I can't pull out corresponding model in the same statement. Without knowing the model I cannot choose the needed row correctly.

I end up with something like this (error), but obviously cannot access alias in subquery:

```
SELECT model, price 
FROM (SELECT price, model FROM Printer WHERE color = 'y') AS colored
 WHERE colored.price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM colored);
```

Comment: You can repeat the same condition in the subquery though and refer to the base table again. Of course if your platform allows ctes then you can do it much like what you attempted to do above.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track with that subquery. The trick is to join your two tables in your main query so you can get the `maker` and `price` and then in your WHERE clause hit up that subquery for the `min(price)`:

```
SELECT
   t1.maker, t2.price
FROM
    Product t1
    INNER JOIN Printer t2
        ON t1.model = t2.model
WHERE price = (SELECT min(price) FROM Printer WHERE color = 'Y')
    and color = 'Y';
```

---

UPDATE: If your condition is more complex than `color = 'Y'` and you want to avoid copy-pasting code around then a CTE may help. A CTE (Common Table Expression) works sort of like a subquery or a view, but it's only in context in the current query.

```
WITH printerCTE AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Printer 
    WHERE color = 'Y'
)
SELECT
   t1.maker, t2.price
FROM
    printerCTE t1
    INNER JOIN Printer t2
        ON t1.model = t2.model
WHERE price = (SELECT min(price) FROM printerCTE);
```

Now you can make your change once in the CTE and it will be reused twice below. Once in the main query and once again in the subquery.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But what would you do to avoid copying if there is a complex condition instead of `color = 'Y'` ?

Comment: I believe a CTE may help here. I'll write that up and post in the answer.